# How to see other users' old tweets?

Tags: twitter, twitter-archive

When I scroll down in an user's timeline, I can only go down so much and the website won't load any more tweets. I tried the search bar and it seems to give tweets from a certain period of time.

[image: screenshot]

I read [this](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-view-someones-old-tweets.2757653/) and tried `Tweetdeck` - it also only allows so much scroll down - and I didn't see a place to specify the date range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Twitter [Advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced), fill out the details in the **People** and **Dates** section.

Or you can directly give the date range in search bar with the Twitter handle. For example: **from:Bloomberg since:2016-01-01 until:2017-11-28**

It will list all the Tweets (including replies) between these dates from *Bloomberg*.

Comment: It doesn't work for me - it won't show up all the tweets. Entering more restrictive dates makes different tweet appear.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong.