# Is it possible to archive all retweets of a given user?

Tags: twitter, tweet, retweet

I'm trying to archive all tweets (including replies), retweets and favorites of a given user.

For archiving all tweets, [this wonderful answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112171/how-to-see-other-users-old-tweets) works.

For archiving all favorites, scrolling down the likes page works.

However, I'm unable to find a way to archive all retweets.

Searching shows only recent retweets.

```
from:username include:nativeretweets filter:nativeretweets since:xxxx-xx-xx until:yyyy-yy-yy
```

Scrolling doesn't show all retweets.

---

If this cannot be done, is there a way to check if a given user has retweeted a tweet (when given the tweet id)?

If this is possible, we can recursively check if a given user has retweeted any of their followings' tweet (or even followings of followings' tweet or ...) Of course, this solution is far from perfect, but it's better than the status quo.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Twitter logs 2 types of retweets:

1. **Native Retweets** - which are made by users clicking the retweet button on Twitter's web app. The search parameter to filter only these would be `filter:nativeretweets`
2. **App Retweets** - which are made via Twitter's mobile apps and via other 3rd party Twitter applications. the search parameter to filter these would be `filter:retweets`

I believe that a search query containing these two parameters with an AND statement would cover both types of retweets.